# Flexbox full parent's width and height with scrollable content

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I have a layout in which it shouldn't overflow the browser window, but there are 2 components (ul and table) that can be bigger than the window's size, so they should be scrollable.

I am using flexbox for this layout, and I have added `overflow-y: auto` for the ul element and `overflow: auto` for the table element. The scrollbar is working for the ul element, but not for the table element.

Any tips on how to get it to work without a fixed height and width in the table element since it needs to fill whatever space is left?

[image]

Here is the source code for that:

[image: Edit flexbox content scrollable]

*Edit 1*: I forgot to mention the sidebar width will be resizable, and I was hoping to avoid that kind of calculation to keep all elements synced. This code later will be ported to react, and re-rendering the app while the user resizes the sidebar width could cause a bad performance I imagine. So, was aiming to handle it all in CSS if that is possible.

Comment: Apply display:flex in your table and try.

Comment: @VimalPatel it didn't work

Comment: Check this out, https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-content-scrollable-forked-gygu9?file=/index.html

Comment: for me it seems more like a css-grid task. Have you tried using `min-width: 100%; max-width: calc(100vw - "sidebar width");` yet?

Comment: @tacoshy I forgot to mention the sidebar width will be resizable, and I was hoping to avoid that kind of calculation to keep all elements synced.

Comment: are you relaying to use flexboxes? I can convert that style to css-grid and make it working as intended.

Comment: @VimalPatel that didn't work quite well yet https://imgur.com/a/uquFijb

Comment: @tacoshy by css-grid you mean `display: grid`? The sidebar can be resizable at the point of disappearing. Would it work with the grid approach? I think I have tried that before, and I didn't have much luck with that. I appreciate if you could give it a try :heart:

Comment: @maxcnunes sorry for the late replay, had some work to do. I managed to fullfill your requirements. Use it in full screen mode to have test it. Tell me if something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late explanation: the body is the grid parent. it is set to `100vw` and `100vh` so it will always fill exactly the screensize. the header and footer have a row height of `min-content` while the content between has the height of `auto` which with the preset height of `100vh` will cause it to span the entire height.

Same count for the `width`. The sidebar has a awidth of min-content. So if the width changes, the content will adept to it.

PS: Because of the defualt snippet preview height you dont see the table. if you extend it to a normal screen height it will be there.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // append li items
  var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("li");
    div.innerHTML = "Test";
    ul.appendChild(div);
  }
  
  // append tr items
  var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  for (let row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
    let innerHTML = "";
    for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
      innerHTML += "<td>" + col + "</td>";
    }
    var div = document.createElement("tr");
    div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    tbody.appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto min-content;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
}

#title,
#footer {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

h1,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

#title,
#nav,
#article,
#footer {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#title,
#footer {
  background: lightgray;
}

#nav {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
}

/* table */

tr {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>My<strong>Application</strong></h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
  <h3>Sidebar</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="article">
  <textarea>
    Something here
  </textarea>
  <div id="table">
    <table>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  Copyright (c) 1017 Nobody Ever
</div>
```